# Packet loss in socket programming java

Tags: java, sockets

I am trying to send a file from client to server. Below is the code i have tried. But at times, there is a packet loss during the transfer. I am not sure where i am wrong.

SERVER SIDE CODE:

```
public static void ReadAndWrite(byte[] aByte, Socket clientSocket,
            InputStream inputStream, String fileOutput)
                    throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        int bytesRead;
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;
        BufferedOutputStream bufferedOutputStream = null;
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try
        {
        fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream( fileOutput );
        bufferedOutputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(fileOutputStream);
        bytesRead = inputStream.read(aByte, 0, aByte.length);
        System.out.println("The length is "+bytesRead);
        int count = 0;
        do {
            count++;
            byteArrayOutputStream.write(aByte);
            bytesRead = inputStream.read(aByte);
        } while (bytesRead != -1);
        System.out.println("The count is "+count);
        System.out.println("The length is "+byteArrayOutputStream.size());
        bufferedOutputStream.write(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray());
        bufferedOutputStream.flush();
        bufferedOutputStream.close();
        clientSocket.close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.writeLog(ex,Listen.class.getName(), LogType.EXCEPTION);  
            throw ex;
        }
```

CLIENT SIDE CODE:

```
public  void readByteArrayAndWriteToClientSocket(
            Socket connectionSocket, BufferedOutputStream outToClient, String fileToSend ) throws Exception
    {
        try{
        if (outToClient != null) 
        {
            File myFile = new File(fileToSend);
            System.out.println(myFile.length());
            byte[] byteArray = new byte[(int) myFile.length()];

            FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;

            try {
                fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(myFile);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.writeLog(ex, FileUtility.class.getName(), LogType.EXCEPTION);
                throw ex;
            }
            BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(fileInputStream);

            try {
                bufferedInputStream.read(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
                outToClient.write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
                outToClient.flush();
                outToClient.close();
                connectionSocket.close();


                return;
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.writeLog(ex, FileUtility.class.getName(), LogType.EXCEPTION);
                throw ex;
            }

        }
        }catch (Exception e) {
            Logger.writeLog(e, getClass().getName(), LogType.EXCEPTION);
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

Comment: The code looks OK.  If you diff the files, where are they different?

Comment: What do you mean by "packet loss"?  Part of the data isn't received?  None of the data is received?  Or inspecting the packets with something like Wireshark shows a packet is dropped?  Occasional packet loss is inevitable over any lossy wire; TCP was designed with this in mind and builds in recovery mechanisms to ensure delivery (when possible) and guarantee ordering and integrity.

Comment: You should not close the `socket` immediately after sending the file. Make it wait for a few seconds before terminating. This would ensure the server actually receives the file.

Comment: @ExtremeCoders: That is absolutely not how Java sockets work.  If it was, how would you know *how long* you have to wait before closing?

Comment: I am trying to transfer a ZIP file of 3500 KB. But the transferred file is only 3450 KB or 3495 KB. Very rarely i get the  full file.

Answer (score 4):

There is no 'packet loss', just bugs in your code.

The canonical way to copy a stream in Java is as follows:

```
while ((count = in.read(buffer)) > 0)
{
   out.write(buffer, 0, count);
}
```

If you know the number of bytes in advance and the sender must keep the connection open after the transfer, it becomes:

```
while (total < expected && (count = in.read(buffer, 0, expected-total > buffer.length ? buffer.length : (int)(expected-total))) > 0)
{
   out.write(buffer, 0, count);
   total += count;
}
```

Forget all the `ByteArrayInput/OutputStreams` and the extra copies. Just read from the file and send to the socket, or read from the socket and write to the file.

Answer (score 3):

The sockets read method will return when its has obtained all the bytes you asked for, OR, when it stops receiving data from the network.

As transmission is often interrupted in any real network you need to keep issuing read calls until you have the number of bytes you want.

You need code something like this:

```
        char [] buffer = new char[1024];
        int expect = 1000;
        int sofar = 0;
       int chars_read;
       try
       {
          while((chars_read = from_server.read(buffer[sofar])) != -1)
          {
             sofar = sofar + chars_read;
             if (sofar >= expected) break;
          }
       }
       catch(IOException e)
       {
          to_user.println(e);
       }
```

Comment: The key here is not to ignore the return value of `read`.  `read(buf, off, len)` does not guarantee it will read `len` bytes; it could read less.  In either case it returns the number of bytes that were actually read.  This goes for reading from the file and from reading from the socket.  Guava's [`ByteStreams.readFully(InputStream, byte[])`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/io/ByteStreams.html) behaves in the way OP is expecting `read` to work, though `ByteStreams.toByteArray()` is simpler.

Comment: How do I fit this to my existing code. I couldn't understand.

Comment: @James: I replaced my code with your's. still facing the same issue

Comment: @All: but everytime I get it right when I do it the SECOND time. only for the FIRST time there is a packet loss. I am wondering how..

Comment: @user3089869 -- sorry cut and pasted incomplete example.

Comment: This doesn't even compile. There is no `read(char)` method. And the buffer should be `byte[]`, not `char[].`

Comment: And the `read()` method doesn't return 'when it stops receiving data from the network'. It blocks.